# Is there a logical gate called grantr?

Tags: logic-gates

Is there a logical gate called grantr?

I do not remember where I have seen that name and I can't shake my mind from the thought that there exists a logical gate ( not function) with that name. Is that true or am I wrong?

Comment: Sounds like the name of a signal not a gate. Like a bus arbiter. That is just a wild guess.

Comment: So there  is no logical gate with that name right?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. My background is that I have a bachelor degree in electrical engineering and have been working as an electrical engineer at the PCB level for about 20 years. I am not an expert in any one area. But I think if a grantr gate existed I would have stumbled upon it by now.

Comment: Most of the word looks like 'grant'. That's a good candidate for a signal name, for instance coming from an arbiter as mkeith suggests. As such, you might find it written on a logic diagram near a signal line, which may also happen to be near a gate output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no logical gate basic or derived  with that name.

OR, AND and NOT are the only ones all the rest are derivations.

Comment: How do you make a NOT gate from a combination of OR and AND? The usual primitives are NOT, NOR and NAND.

Comment: Ok I will include NOT, but really it doesn't gate anything, Just inverts. But your right in that it is a basic logical operation.

Comment: I wouldn't consider AND and OR the basics, since NAND and NOR are simpler to implement.

Comment: In CMOS logic, NAND, NOR and NOT are the primitives and all other are derivations. In some other logic than CMOS, things might be different, even if not relevant any more.

Comment: Well, there is a concept of logical completeness. I think if you say that everything else is a derivative of AND and OR, then you ought to be able to show me how to make an inverter from AND and OR. The reason being that many logic functions cannot be implemented without an inverter. For example, how can you implement XOR from AND and OR without using  an inverter?